# AngularJs raw template shows briefly on IOS before being replaced

Tags: iphone, performance, cordova, angularjs

I've a mobile site based on angularJs, on a normal machine it looks fine.
When I take it to IOS.  I notice that the raw template is shown briefly before the text is replaced by angularJs.

i.e. i have {{TitleText}} show up briefly, before I see it being replaced.
It seems to be more apparent on iphone than ipad, I guess from the performance of the machine.
It's also more apparent on logic heavy pages..

My question is that is there a way to prevent the raw template from displaying on slower browsers? maybe a built in loading screen to hide the details until the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`ng-bind`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBind)

```
<h1 ng-bind="TitleText"></h1>
```

In slower browsers the element will appear empty until angular has finished loading

Edit: Instead of an empty element, placeholder text can be used.

```
<h1 ng-bind="TitleText">Loading Title...</h1>
```

"Loading Title..." will be replaced with the value of `TitleText` after angular has finished loading.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried ng-bind, it works for some situations, but just having the text dissapear seems to break the CSS on some of my pages. will be trying ng-cloak next.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are after, but instead of an empty element, you can have placeholder text which will be displayed while AngularJS is loading.
I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to the use of ng-bind is [ng-cloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak)